# Apache POI 522 and SUMPRODUCT(ABS(A1:A5)) formula evaluation

Tags: excel, apache-poi

SUMPRODUCT(ABS(A1:A5)) formula evaluation does not return correct value. Is this known defect in the Apache POI 522.?  but SUMPRODUCT() works, if I don't give ABS() inside the function. please let me know. please find the test program I have created for this issue.

```
private static final String FILE_NAME = "C:\\Ruff\\Math Functionality (1).xlsx";
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    try 
    {
         Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
         DataFormatter dataFormat = new DataFormatter(locale);
         FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_NAME));
         Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);

        // get the cell with the offending formula (cell A3 in sheet 0)
        Cell c = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(2).getCell(1);

        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        evaluator.evaluateAll();
        //evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(c);
        CellValue cVal = evaluator.evaluate(c); 
        switch (cVal.getCellType())
        {
            case NUMERIC:
            System.out.println("Cell value:" + dataFormat.formatCellValue(c,evaluator));
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

}

Comment: The ABS(A1:A5) behaviour is not defined in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/abs-function-3420200f-5628-4e8c-99da-c99d7c87713c - POI does not expect ABS to take a range as input and it only appears to calculate for the first cell in the range.

Comment: I added https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66303 - I think fixing this in POI will be a very big task and I'm not sure if anyone has the time to take it on.

Comment: btw there is no need to formula evaluate on xls/xlsx files that were created by Excel - Excel stores the evaluated result as well as the formula - you just need to use dataFormat.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true) and dataFormat.formatCellValue(c) as opposed to dataFormat.formatCellValue(c, formulaEvaluator)